# How to read the files concurrently from different folders but in a specific order within each folder?

Tags: multithreading, apache-camel

I want to use apache camel file component.

I have a requirement where there are  multiple files in different folders.
I want to read files under those directories in an order (based on timestamp).

**Note:** All these directories will be the subdirectories of the root.

> **Eg:** root-
>
> ```
>      /dir1 - file1, file2, file3
>
>      /dir2  - file4, file5, file6
> ```

What I need here is,

1 thread should read all files in dir1 based on timestamp and other thread should read from dir2.

What I am doing now is,

```
from("file:/root/?recursive=true&sortBy=file:modified").threads(10).to("another component");
```

But this is not working the way I wanted, instead it is assigning different threads to different files and so the order of processing is not achieved.

Please let me know how to achieve my requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a dynamic router to route to different consumers based on the directory the file is in. eg suppose you want three processors running in parallel:

```
from("file:/root?sortBy=file:modified)
.to("myDynamicRouter")

from("seda:myQueue0")
.to("myProcessor")

from("seda:myQueue1")
.to("myProcessor")

from("seda:myQueue2")
.to("myProcessor")
```

MyDynamicRouter is a router which will return the name of a SEDA queue based on the directory of the file (see http://camel.apache.org/dynamic-router.html)

eg

```
public void process(File file) {
    String queueName = "seda:MyQueue" + (file.getParent().hashCode() % 3);
    return queueName;
}
```

So all the files will be read from the different directories in date order. When they get put on the various seda queues they will remain in date order. As all files from the same directory are put on the same queue, they will be processed in date order.

One thing to watch is that files from different directories may be interleaved together in the same processor. Without a lot of work and some blocking going that, is just something you'll have to allow for when coding your processor.

Comment: Hi Matt, the no. of directories are not fixed/known. They get created at runtime. Is there a way that Camel assigns only 1 thread to 1 directory, so that the processing order can be maintained?

Comment: Yes it can but you'll need to do more processing in the route as Camel won't split files to different threads based on the directory. It's nearly lunch, let me see if I can update my answer.

Comment: I've edited my answer to give a more general solution