# Apache Camel file component to use different directories

Tags: apache-camel

Is there an option in Apache camel file component to use multiple different directory from where files can be read.

```
\
  - home
     - level1
        - level2
          - input   (files are within this folder)
  - dir1
     - test 
        - folder1  ( set of files in this folder)
        - folder2  ( set of files in this folder)
```

Another option is using [dynamic routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721576/how-to-read-the-files-concurrently-from-different-folders-but-in-a-specific-orde), when the folders are under same directory.

But my use case i can't move files to a common directory, i need the input directory structure to be the same and as two different directories.

is there any option like below?

```
<from uri="file://home/leve1/level2/input,//dir1/test/folder1,//dir1/test/folder2"/>
<to ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another thing to consider here is `recursive` option which you could use along with `antInclude` or `include` options. In this case you will be able to poll different directories with just one consumer, e.g.

```
<from uri="file://dir1/test?recursive=true&amp;antInclude=folder1/*,folder2/*" />
```

Note though, this would be very inefficient if you poll recursively too big file trees

Answer (score 2):

The `file` component accept 1 path as input (for context path). Instead of multiple paths in single `file` component, you could consider having multiple `file` component.

- Use multiple from EIP and point to same endpoint

```xml
<from uri="file://home/leve1/level2/input" />
    <to uri="direct:file-handler" />

<from uri="file://dir1/test/folder1" />
    <to uri="direct:file-handler" />

<from uri="file://dir1/test/folder2" />
    <to uri="direct:file-handler" />

<from uri="direct:file-handler" />
    <!-- your logic goes here -->
```